# Duplicating a Mongoose document with subdocs, duplicated id of subdocs are allowed?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

To clarify: I have a document with a subdoc. I create a new document with the same data of the other one and it gets a new id. However, when I copy the subdoc array they do not get a new id.

Are subdocs id local to the parent doc? I.e. would the following be a problem?

```
[
    {
        "__v": 1,
        "_id": "5214af03a9f53efa61000004",
        "name": "Foo",
        "subdocs": [
            {
                "thing": "value",
                "_id": "5214af03a9f53efa61000006"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "__v": 0,
        "name": "Foo",
        "_id": "5214af03a9f53efa61000014",
        "subdocs": [
            {
                "thing": "value",
                "_id": "5214af03a9f53efa61000006"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a unique index on the `_id` field of documents stored directly in a collection, but not for embedded documents, nor is there any requirement that embedded documents have an `_id` field at all. The two documents you have provided are both valid to be stored in MongoDB in the same database (I'm interpreting your example as an array of two documents that are both stored directly in a collection together).